# Creating an extension method for HtmlHelper that takes an Action<T> causing auto formatting issues in VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2017, html-helper

**Current code**

I have created an extension method for `HtmlHelper` that is defined as follows:

```
public static IHtmlString MyMethod(this HtmlHelper helper, Action<MyClass> action)
{
    MyClass settings = new MyClass();
    action(settings);
    // Here I can now use the settings as defined in razor view.
}
```

The purpose of creating the extension method in this way is so that I can call it by allowing the `MyClass` class to be defined in the razor view like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.MyMethod(settings =>
    {
        settings.SomeFunction(1, 2, 3);
    })
</div>
```

**The problem**

Now this works great and does exactly what I expect. However, the 1 issue is that every time I do "Format Document" (Ctrl + E, D) in Visual Studio, all lines after the first line get indented another tab. Just to be clear, after formatting the document 4 times it would look something like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.MyMethod(settings =>
                    {
                        settings.SomeFunction(1, 2, 3);
                    })
</div>
```

It seems that the problem only happens when used inside an element (in this example `div`). But that is something that I would need to be able to use.

In a view that I am modifying often it does't take long until I have auto formatted them off the visible screen space. I then need to manually move them back. Needless to say this is very annoying, especially when used multiple times in a single view.

I am currently using Visual Studio 2017, I am not sure if this problem exists in previous versions or not.

**What I have tried**

I have tried different ways of writing the code in an attempt to stop it, but it always formats to the same problem. So for example I moving the `settings` to the 2nd line, move the opening `{` to the first line. Nothing seems to work. A couple of examples:

```
@Html.MyMethod(
settings =>
{
    settings.SomeFunction(1, 2, 3);
})

@Html.MyMethod(settings => {
    settings.SomeFunction(1, 2, 3);
})
```

**The question**

Why is this happening, and what can I do to stop it? I am open to redefining the extension method if that is the problem, as long as I can call it in the same way I have shown above.

---

Just a note, for anyone that has used DevExpress MVC library, that allows similar functionality but somehow that doesn't seem to suffer from this particular problem. I don't know what they have done differently though, I just know somehow this functionality should be achievable without causing this formatting problem.

Answer (score 0):

The formatter for Razor files is terrible. The issues you mention seem fairly mild - it can get far worse. This is a long-standing problem which predates MVC; the formatter for ASPX pages was just as bad.

Razor files are a mixture of 5 languages, each of which have different formatting needs:

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript
- C# or Visual Basic
- Razor

Perhaps it is forgivable that Microsoft have not got the formatting right in every situation. Actually i think they have given up trying.

To fix the formatting problems, I would suggest pressing Control-Z immediately after it formats incorrectly. That will undo the formatting, without undoing the change which triggered it.

Comment: Unfortunately, CTRL+Z isn't a suitable work around because it resets *all* of the auto formatting, even the correct parts. I don't see why the mix of languages really, the parser seems to do fine when working out compilation warnings/errors with the mix of code, so not sure why the formatting is so difficult. Though I agree about it being an ongoing problem, I have certainly had worse problems with the editor in past versions of VS.

Comment: Well it's a good question. The formatting causes me trouble every day, and control-z is the only workaround i have found so far.